# Delete decimals of a GeoJson elevation values

Tags: javascript, regex, geojson

I have a GeoJson file that looks like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "name": "first"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        22.59323,
        44.71464,
        233.6
      ],
      [
        22.59274,
        44.71425,
        231.8
      ],
      [
        22.59264,
        44.71405,
        230.7
      ],.........
```

Every third value in coordinates represents the elevation at that point. Is there any (non-manual) way I could delete the decimals from this values? I think of something like a regex, using Notepad++, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: yes, use javascript to target the coordinates and use `Math.floor`

Comment: I think you would want to round them? why don't you just read everything from coordinates round and then put back there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the features, then over the geometry and use `Math.floor()` on the elevation:

```
featureCollection.features.forEach(function (feature) {
    feature.geometry.coordinates.forEach(function (coordinates) {
        coordinates[2] = Math.floor(coordinates[2]);
    });
});
```

Comment: This works fine, altough I'm not sure which is the best way to save the old file with the new values

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression. You could try looking for several digits in a row, followed by a dot.

`/((\d\d\d?)\.(.*)/`

Find two to three digits, a dot, and then whatever else is on the line. You could replace it using something like this: `\1\2`. That takes the first bit inside parentheses, and the second bit (leaving out the period).